# Display data from dimensional JSON array in VBA, getting "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch" an error message

Tags: arrays, json, excel, vba, multidimensional-array

I'm new to StackOverflow, and I'm struggling with displaying data from a dimensional JSON array in VBA (Excel). Could you please help?
Below are the codes I'm using for displaying the data of "ShippingMethod" from the JSON.

Example of JSON:
As you are able to see the "Data" is the first object.
"Shipments" and "DisplayItems" are the array of "Data".

[image]

Also, there are multiple objects inside the "Shipments" array.
For example "ShippingMethod" and "ShippingName", and my goal is to display the data of these objects. ("LC") and ("No Charge - Lowest Cost 3-5 Day Delivery")

[image]

**Here are my codes:**
**First method:**

```
 Dim Json1 As Dictionary
 Set Json1 = JsonConverter.ParseJson(strResponse3)
 home.Activate

 home.Cells(x, 2) = Json1("Data")("Shipments")(1)("ShippingMethod")
```

**Second method:**

```
Dim Json1 As Dictionary
 Set Json1 = JsonConverter.ParseJson(strResponse3)
 home.Activate

x = 42

    For Each Item In Json1("Data")("Shipments")
    home.Cells(x, 2) = Item("ShippingMethod")
    
    x = x + 1
    
    Next
```

I'm not able to display the data of these "ShippingMethod" and "ShippingName" objects as I'm getting an error message "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch" from the VBA.
NOTE: I'm using the same method on another JSON XML, it's able to retrieve the data from the dimensional JSON array without any issues.

Update on my codes(7/8)

```
Dim Json1 As Dictionary, x As Long, y As Long
Dim shipments

home.Activate

x = 42
  
Set Json1 = JsonConverter.ParseJson(strResponse3)

  
Set shipments = Json1("Data")("Shipments")  '<-- Getting error "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch"'

For y = 3 To shipments.count
    home.Cells(x, 2) = shipments(y)("ShippingMethod")
    
    x = x + 1
    
Next
```

[Error message_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RINWP.png) for `Set shipments = Json1("Data")("Shipments")`
The VBA highlight this line of code after selecting "Debug" button.

Note: try the below debug.print. However, the data returned as "0".

```
Debug.Print VarType(Json1("Data")("Shipments"))
```

Update on my codes(7/21)

Dim Json1 As Dictionary, x As Long, y As Long
Dim FSO, ts, s As String
Dim shipments

```
home.Activate

 ' write json to file
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
s = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\strResponse3.json"
Set ts = FSO.CreateTextFile(s)
ts.Write strResponse3
ts.Close
MsgBox Len(strResponse3) & " bytes written to " & s

x = 42
 
Set Json1 = JsonConverter.ParseJson(strResponse3)

Debug.Print "Json1", VarType(Json1)
Debug.Print "Json1(Data)", VarType(Json1("Data"))
Debug.Print "Json1(Data)(PriceSummary)", VarType(Json1("Data")("PriceSummary"))
Debug.Print "Json1(Data)(Shipments)", VarType(Json1("Data")("Shipments"))
Debug.Print "Json1(Data)(DisplayItems)", VarType(Json1("Data")("DisplayItems"))

home.Cells(x, 1) = Json1("Data")("Orders")("ShipmentId")

Set shipments = Json1("Data")("Shipments")
'home.Activate

For i = 1 To shipments.count
    Cells(x, 2) = shipments(i)("ShippingMethod")
    x = x + 1
Next
```

In the Txt output file, I noticed it only returning the data of "Data":{"PriceSummary":{,. Please see the beginning of the data [TXT OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRLxb.png) screenshot and compare it with the [JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmgR0.png) screenshot.
Also, please check the ending of the data [TXT OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0juZ.png)and compare it with the [JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2zgV.png) screenshot. The data only contain whenever inside the "PurchaseSummary" and there is no data with the arrays "Shipment" and "DisplayItems".

Here's the [Debug.Print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhRGX.png) screenshot. No data returns for Shipments and DisplayItems.
I strongly believe there is something wrong with the JSON. (Kindly please refer back to the very first screenshot for the JSON pattern)

Debug.Print result:
Json1          9

Json1(Data)    9

Json1(Data)(PriceSummary)    9

Json1(Data)(Shipments)       0

Json1(Data)(DisplayItems)    0

Comment: FYI JSON and XML are not the same thing - that are both useful data exchange formats, but there is no "JSON XML" so I'd avoid using that term.

Comment: Thank you @Tim Williams for your information, I will avoid using the same term together in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update - added JSON file export and test data.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub test()
    Dim Json1 As Dictionary, x As Long, i As Long
    Dim shipments
    Dim FSO, ts, strResponse3 As String, s As String

    strResponse3 = "{""Data"" : {" & _
    """Shipments"":[" & _
    "{""ShippingMethod"":""LC""}," & _
    "{""ShippingMethod"":""LC""}," & _
    "{""ShippingMethod"":""LC""}" & _
    "]}}"

    ' write json to file
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    s = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\strResponse3.json"
    Set ts = FSO.CreateTextFile(s)
    ts.Write strResponse3
    ts.Close
    MsgBox Len(strResponse3) & " bytes written to " & s

    Set Json1 = JsonConverter.ParseJson(strResponse3)
    Debug.Print "Json1", VarType(Json1)
    Debug.Print "Json1(Data)", VarType(Json1("Data"))
    Debug.Print "Json1(Data)(Shipments)", VarType(Json1("Data")("Shipments"))

    Set shipments = Json1("Data")("Shipments")
    'home.Activate
    x = 42
    For i = 1 To shipments.Count
        Cells(x, 2) = shipments(i)("ShippingMethod")
        x = x + 1
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I tried to code using the same but unfortunately still getting the "Type mismatch" errors while debugging on the line: Set shipments = Json1("Data")("Shipments") <-- this line is getting an error.

Comment: That code works for me with your posted JSON, so maybe you're not getting the response you expect?

Comment: Set shipments = Json1("Data")("Shipments") this line is getting an error when debugged. 
Strange, the code works on calling data from other arrays, but not on the "Shipment" & "DisplayItems" from the posted JSON.

Comment: I've just posted my updated code at the bottom of my post, please refer to "Update on my codes(7/8)" .

Comment: @Raiden What do you get with `Debug.print VarType(Json1("Data")("Shipments"))`

Comment: Hi @CDP1802, many thanks! Tried to execute the given code, and the data returned as "0". I had posted the screenshot "DebugPrint_Screenshot" at the bottom of my post.

Comment: @Raiden 0 means [empty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/user-interface-help/vartype-function). I have updated my code to write the JSON text out to a file so you can confirm it is as expected.

Comment: Hi @CDP1802, thanks again! yes, that's my expected output! do you have any ideas on how can I pull the data? I believe you had manually inserted the data as "LC" into that object. However, while calling different JSON might have different data instead of "LC".

Comment: @raiden That was just test data. Did you replace strResonse3 with the real data and did the text file created match the screenshot you posted ? What was the msgbox and debug output?

Comment: Hi @CDP1802, I just did what you had asked. You may please refer to my latest post "Update on my codes(7/13)". No data returns for "Shipment" & "DisplayItems". According to the JSON, both of these arrays are having data. But whenever we tried to print it always returning as a "0" result.  I strongly believe there is something wrong with the JSON instead of the code here.

Comment: Hi @CDP1802, I still can't figure out the resolution by trying multiple methods for retrieving the data from "Shipment" & "DisplayItems". However, those method works perfectly on other JSON. Only the particular JSON is not returning the data...Thank you for your help btw, appreciated that!

Comment: @raiden Can you share the file on a dropbox ?

Comment: Hi @CDP1802, Sure. Do you have any URLs or the steps to share the JSON file with you on dropbox?

Comment: Hi @CDP1802, I had just updated my codes again. If you refer to the print result, the (9) set of data only returned to (Data) and (Price Summary). the rest (Shipments) and (DisplayItems) are not having any data. >>>>> 
Debug.Print result: Json1 9

Json1(Data) 9

Json1(Data)(PriceSummary) 9

Json1(Data)(Shipments) 0

Json1(Data)(DisplayItems) 0